# In The Walking Dead, how come all the characters don't go up north a bit, where all the zombies would be dead from the first winter freeze?

Tags: the-walking-dead

From what I understand, being frozen solid (regardless of if you're warmed up again), causes the water in cells to crystallize (unless it's done *extremely* quickly. This would mean the brains of zombies would be quickly destroyed. The only zombies left would be the ones freshly made from dead humans, or the ones underground, where the temperature stays at a fixed level more or less throughout the year.

Zombies in houses would die, since there's no more electricity/gas/etc keeping the houses warm.

You could simply survive past the first time it goes below freezing for more than a couple days straight, and you'd be good.

I know that even Georgia is capable of hosting temperatures below 0 degrees Celsius, so I'm not sure how the slow-moving zombies are surviving. Perhaps an enormous pack of zombies could stay alive for a little while in sub-zero temperatures, but the cold would eventually reach them all, and they'd all die...

Comment: Just saying, the zombies in _Game of Thrones_ have no problem with the cold...

Comment: Trying to apply science to the operation of zombies, even on *The Walking Dead*, often doesn't end up well.

Comment: I'd totally kill sales.

Comment: I disagree. I think they could make a great story of the characters fighting to get up north in the first year, then trying to stay alive with everyone else, perhaps turning into a squad in some army whos purpose it is to explore the zombie-infested lands, saving people and tracking herds

Comment: Zombies are magic.

Comment: The same reason why they don't die from starvation, loss of limb, zero blood flow, etc.

Comment: Is this strictly asking comic or tv show? I vaguely recall characters in the 2nd season of the telltale game going north for similar reasons. would need to double check

Comment: I'm talking about in the TV-Show.

Comment: VTC.   "Why didn't they do this?" and especially basing the question on some real-world science-based logic is pointless.